# Load module-wide config in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, module, package

Let's assume, that there are following minimalistic python classes inside one module, e.g. `Module`:

```
module/
   __init__.py
   db.py
   document.py
```

db.py

```
import yaml

class DB(object):
    config = {}

    @classmethod
    def load_config(cls, config_path):
        cls.config = yaml.load(open(config_path, 'r').read())
```

and document.py

```py
from .db import DB

class Document(object):
    db = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DB()
```

End-user is going to use such `Module` as follows:

```py
from Module import DB, Document

DB.load_config('/path/to/config.yml')

Document.do_some_stuff()

doc1 = Document()
doc2 = Document.find(...)
doc2.update_something(...)
doc2.save()
```

It is expected that `Document` class and every instance of it will have internally an access to class `DB` with a config specified by user. However, since `Document` performs an internal import of `DB` class (`from .db import DB`) it receives a 'fresh' `DB` class with default config.

I did a lot of searches, most of questions and answers are about module-wide configs, but not specified by the end user.

How can I achieve such functionality? I guess that there is some architectural problem here, but what is the most simple way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this isn't the most *appropriate* answer, but a few months back I wrote a module called [`aconf`](https://github.com/synchronizing/aconf) for this exact purpose. It's a memory-based global configuration module for Python written in 8 lines. The idea is you can do the following:

You create a `Config` object to force the user to input the configuration your program requires (in this case it's inside `config.py`):

```py
""" 'Config' class to hold our desired configuration parameters. 

Note:
    This is technically not needed. We do this so that the user knows what he/she should pass 
    as a config for the specific project. Note how we also take in a function object - this is
    to demonstrate that one can have absolutely any type in the global config and is not subjected
    to any limitations.
"""

from aconf import make_config

class Config:
    def __init__(self, arg, func):
        make_config(arg=arg, func=func)
```

You consume your configuration throughout your module (in this case, inside `functionality.py`):

```py
""" Use of the global configuration through the `conf` function. """

from aconf import conf

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        func = conf().func
        arg = conf().arg

        self.arg = func(arg)
```

And then use it (in this case inside `main.py`):

```py
from project.config import Config
from project.functionality import Example

# Random function to demonstrate we can pass _anything_ to 'make_config' inside 'Config'.
def uppercase(words):
    return words.upper()

# We create our custom configuration without saving it.
Config(arg="hello world", func=uppercase)

# We initialize our Example object without passing the 'Config' object to it.
example = Example()
print(example.arg) 
# >>> "HELLO WORLD"
```

The entire `aconf` module is the following:

```
__version__ = "1.0.1"
import namedtupled

def make_config(**kwargs):
    globals()["aconf"] = kwargs

conf = lambda: namedtupled.map(globals()["aconf"])
config = lambda: globals()["aconf"]
```

... in essence, you just save your configuration to `globals()` during runtime.

It's so stupid it makes me wonder if you should even be allowed to do this. I wrote `aconf` for fun, but have never personally used it in a big project. The reality is, you might run into the problem of making your code weird for other developers.